# How do I get my code to recall upon the function again to start over? (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, integer, user-input

Here is my code that I am working on. It is supposed to take a number from the user and if its a perfect number it says so, but if its not it asks to enter a new number. When I get to the enter a new number part, it doesn't register my input. Can someone help me out?

```
def isPerfect(num):
    if num <= 0:                  
        return False
    total = 0                      
    for i in range(1,num):
        if num%i== 0:
            total = total + i
    if total == num:
        return True
    else:
        return False


def main():
    num = int(input("Enter a perfect integer: "))
    if isPerfect(num) == False:
        op = int(input(f"{num} is not a perfect number. Re-enter:"))
        isPerfect(op)
    elif isPerfect(num) == True:
        print("Congratulations!",num, 'is a perfect number.')

if __name__ == '__main__':
   main()
```

Comment: a sample run of what I am trying to do: Enter a perfect number: 8
8 is not a perfect number. Re-enter: -1
-1 is not a perfect number. Re-enter: 6
Congratulations! 6 is a perfect number.

Comment: You don't have to use a while loop. You can just call `main()` again  inside of the `False` variation, however its probably better to use a loop. Also since it is a boolean, you don't have to say `== False` or `== True`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could just put a while True loop into your main function like so:

```
def main():
    first_run = True
    perfect_num_received = False
    while not perfect_num_received:
        if first_run:
            num = int(input("Enter a perfect integer: "))
            first_run = False
        if isPerfect(num) == False:
            num = int(input(f"{num} is not a perfect number. Re-enter:"))
        elif isPerfect(num) == True:
            perfect_num_received = True
            print("Congratulations!",num, 'is a perfect number.')
```

but also there is already a built in function to check for the data type of a variable so you could just do something like this maybe:

```
if type(num) == int:
    ...
```

Comment: while this works in starting my entire code over again, I am trying to have it just redo isPerfect() with a new number taken from the user. A sample run of what I'm looking for is: Enter a perfect number: 8
8 is not a perfect number. Re-enter: -1
-1 is not a perfect number. Re-enter: 6
Congratulations! 6 is a perfect number.

Comment: well i mean you have to get a new input to give to the isPerfect() function so you have to get another input after each time you use the function. or do i not understand the question correctly?

Comment: yes you are right but look at my comment on my post. I am trying to get a new input from the string "Re-enter:" but when i enter a number it does not work.

Comment: @Ryan now it should work, basically you just check if you run through it for the first time and after that you just set a new num when it is not a perfect number and if it is the program finishes

Comment: Yup that's exactly what I needed!! Life saver, thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

From the problem description, I assume that the program should terminate after the perfect number is found. There are two things which can be added, a **loop** to go over the input prompt each time the user feeds a number and a **break** condition after finding the perfect number. Here's one implementation which works.

```
def main():
while True:
    num = int(input("Enter a perfect integer: "))
    if isPerfect(num) == False:
        num = int(input(f"{num} is not a perfect number. Re-enter: "))
        isPerfect(num)
    elif isPerfect(num) == True:
        print("Congratulations! ",num, ' is a perfect number.')
        break
```